# How to specify subfolder of DataDirectory in C#

Tags: c#, datadirectory

I'm fairly new to C# programming and I'm working on a windows form application in VS2012 where I need to retrieve data from an SQL database, as well as load images into a picturebox.
I've managed to succesfully connect to the database, by using either an absolute path description (like "D:\ProjectFolder\DbaseFolder\Dbase.sdf") or by using a relative path to the datadirectory, like this:

```
myConnection.ConnectionString = 
"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\Dbase.sdf";
```

This works. However, I want to place my database in a subfolder of the datadirectory, but I can't figure out how to make my connectionstring. I was thinking along the lines of:

```
myConnection.ConnectionString = 
"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\DbaseFolder\\DbFilm.sdf";
```

But that doesn't work. The same problem goes for placing images into a picturebox. How do I make a relative path to a subfolder of the datadirectory?

Comment: You usually don't want to point to a sdf file on your connection string. Also, it should go in your app.config or web.config for a web application. If you're working on a local sql server your connection string should look something like this: `Server=.;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;` You can look up more connection strings on: https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2012/

Comment: Thank you Andrei. I've tried with information from connectionstrings.com, but could you please give me another nudge in the right direction? I want to use a local database (DbFilm.sdf) in a subfolder (\Dbase) inside the application folder. What should my connectionstring look like?

Comment: If you really want to use a local database, you can go with this: `"Server=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Integrated Security=true;AttachDbFileName=C:\Users\John\Documents\Visual Studio2013\Projects\ADONET2ConnectedExpress\Database1.mdf"`. If you setting this on your c# code and not on the app.config then you need to escape the backslashes with another backslash

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, Andrei. However, I see you use an absolute path (C:\Users\...). I would like to use a relative path (something like |DataDirectory|\\Subfolder\...), so that the enduser can install the application in whatever folder he prefers, and the application will still find the database in the subfolder of the application folder.

Comment: I'm pretty sure ..\ notation would work there. In that case your |DataDirectory| would be wherever your application is running. Give it a few tries.

Comment: I'm sorry, still no luck :( I've tried with "Server=(LocalDB)\\v11.0;Integrated Security=true;AttachDbFileName=D:\Local\ProjectFolder\\Dbase\\DbFilm.sdf", no luck. "Data Source=..\\Dbase\\DbFilm.sdf", no luck. "Data Source=|DataDirectory|..\\Dbase\DbFilm.sdf" and several variations, but no luck. The only thing that works is as mentioned above, with the DB in the root application folder. Can I please trouble you for any other suggestion?

Comment: Please refer to http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-compact/ . From that page, you could do this: `Data Source=" + System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase) + "\\DbaseFolder\\DbFilm.sdf;`

Comment: :-( I feel like I'm so close, and yet no success. I notice that your solution points to the bin\Debug folder. I've copied my database to both \Debug and to \Debug\DbaseFolder, and I've tried several variations in the connectionstring, but still I cannot connect to it. Thanks for your patience, but I'm afraid I'm still at a loss.

Comment: I noticed that you have Dbase.sdf and DbFilm.sdf(different database names). Maybe you are mixing those up and that's why you can't find the db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I went ahead and created a [sample project and uploaded it to my GitHub page](https://github.com/ajdvoynos/SQLServer-Compact-Sample).

The following code works perfectly fine for me:

```
    using (var con = new SqlCeConnection())
    {
        con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source = |DataDirectory|\Database\DB.sdf;Persist Security Info=False";
        var cmd = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM TEST", con);
        con.Open();
        var data = new DataTable("whatever");
        data.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
        con.Close();
    }
```

I also included the connection string on the app.config on the sample so you can use it as a best practice. You can download the project as a zip from this [link](https://github.com/ajdvoynos/SQLServer-Compact-Sample/archive/24144a7c4d35003c334617f9406e652d9f66d79b.zip)

Comment: Dbase.sdf was just an example, I'm only working with DbFilm.sdf. Anyway, thank you kindly for your example. I'm going to try this asap, and I'll let you know. Thank you very much!

Comment: Andrei, I tip my hat for you, good sir! With your example and some more fiddling, I was finally able to get my code right. It's working fine now. Thank you very much!